# How to Configure Android Studio to Show Java 11 Code (Not Decompiled Code) When Using Control Click

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When using Android Studio, I would like to be able to control click on a standard Java 11 class or method and see the underlying code.  When I do it now I get the decompiled Java code, which is nice.  But from a debugging and learning perspective I would rather see the real Java source code along with embedded documentation.  I am using Android Studio's built in Java 11.

Edit #1:
I have the box checked for Sources for Android 32 and my build.gradle for Android contains "compileSdkVersion 32".

I probably need to take a step back to explain that I am using libGDX, which typically contains multiple modules.  When working with Android, libGDX will use a module for each of the following - Android, desktop, and core.  It seems that the ability to access the actual source via control click on a standard Java 11 class or method, such as String or ArrayList, works fine in the Android module, but not in the other modules (where I get decompiled code).

I suspect I need to update the build.gradle for each of the other modules to somehow let Android Studio know where the Java source resides, in this case in the default JDK that comes with Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the Android SDK, the source code is not yet available, you must downgrade to version 32 if you want to see the source code.

check 'sources for Android 32' if you haven't already, as shown in the image below (click on the SKD Manager button in the upper right edge to see this image):

[image]

And then in build.gradle make sure you have compileSdk 32 as shown in the code below:

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdo.texteditorapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Abdo21.  I've added more information about the issue to the original post.

Comment: I tested it on libGDX version 1.11.0 in other modules (desktop and android) and it works for me too. just make sure you have compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion equal to 32

Comment: I have both of those set to 32 in my build.gradle for android and control click works as expected in the android module.  In core I can click on a libGDX class/method and it pulls up the real code and doc, but if I click on a plain Java class, such as String or ArrayList, then I get the decompiled code.  Are you saying you get the real code and doc if you click on a plain Java class, such as String or ArrayList, in core?